# How to cycle through delimited tokens with a Regular Expression?

Tags: regex

How can I create a regular expression that will grab delimited text from a string?  For example, given a string like

```
text ###token1### text text ###token2### text text
```

I want a regex that will pull out `###token1###`.  Yes, I do want the delimiter as well.  By adding another group, I can get both:

```
(###(.+?)###)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/###(.+?)###/
```

if you want the ###'s  then you need

```
/(###.+?###)/
```

the **?** means non greedy, if you didn't have the **?**, then it would grab too much.

e.g. `'###token1### text text ###token2###'` would all get grabbed.

My initial answer had a * instead of a +.  * means 0 or more.  + means 1 or more.  * was wrong because that would allow ###### as a valid thing to find.

For playing around with regular expressions. I highly recommend http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/ for windows.  You can type in the string you want and your regular expression and see what it's actually doing.

Your selected text will be stored in \1   or $1 depending on where you are using your regular expression.

Comment: Just a note that in Java, this would be in group(1) from the matcher instance after the last call to find()

Answer (score 1):

In Perl, you actually want something like this:

```
$text = 'text ###token1### text text ###token2### text text';

while($text =~ m/###(.+?)###/g) {
  print $1, "\n";
}
```

Which will give you each token in turn within the while loop. The (.*?) ensures that you get the *shortest* bit between the delimiters, preventing it from thinking the token is 'token1### text text ###token2'.

Or, if you just want to save them, not loop immediately:

```
@tokens = $text =~ m/###(.+?)###/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to match ###token2### as well...

```
/###.+###/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use () and \x. A naive example that assumes the text within the tokens is always delimited by #:

```
text (#+.+#+) text text (#+.+#+) text text
```

The stuff in the () can then be grabbed by using \1 and \2 (\1 for the first set, \2 for the second in the replacement expression (assuming you're doing a search/replace in an editor). For example, the replacement expression could be:

```
token1: \1, token2: \2
```

For the above example, that should produce:

```
token1: ###token1###, token2: ###token2###
```

If you're using a regexp library in a program, you'd presumably call a function to get at the contents first and second token, which you've indicated with the ()s around them.

Answer (score 0):

Well when you are using delimiters such as this basically you just grab the first one then anything that does not match the ending delimiter followed by the ending delimiter. A special caution should be that in cases as the example above [^#] would not work as checking to ensure the end delimiter is not there since a singe # would cause the regex to fail (ie. "###foo#bar###). In the case above the regex to parse it would be the following assuming empty tokens are allowed (if not, change * to +):

###([^#]|#[^#]|##[^#])*###